# How do I get multiple scores to append to the same line?

Tags: python, append

I have been set a task where I have a maths quiz that students take three times and then their scores are saved to a .txt file. The problem I am having is that, because they have to run the quiz 3 times, the 'name' variable gets reset every time and their scores save to three seperate lines in the text file. How can I get it so that the program recognizes if the person has played before and will there save the score to the same line within the text file?

Inside the text file created, it currently looks like this -

```
Tom , 10
Tom , 5
Tom , 3
```

How can I get it to -

```
Tom , 10 , 5 , 3
```

My quiz code:

```
import time

print ('What is your name?')
name = input()
print (' Hello ' + name +', Welcome to the python maths quiz, you will be asked 10 maths questions and marked out of 10 at the end, good luck! ')
time.sleep (1)
Class=input("Which class are you in? 1,2 or 3?")

import random

score = 0
for x in range (10):
    ops = ['+', '-', '*']
    num1 = random.randint(1,10)
    num2 = random.randint(1,10)
    op = random.choice(ops)
    question = '{} {} {}?'.format(num1, op, num2)
    print ('What is '+ question + '?')
    answer = input()

    if op is ("+") :
        rightanswer = num1+num2
        if answer == str(rightanswer):
            print('Well done, that is correct')
            score = score + 1
        else:
            print('Wrong, the correct answer was',rightanswer,'!')

    if op is ("-") :
        rightanswer = num1-num2    
        if answer == str(rightanswer):
            print('Well done, that is correct')
            score = score + 1
        else:
            print('Wrong, the correct answer was',rightanswer,'!')

    elif op is ("*") :
        rightanswer = num1*num2
        if answer == str(rightanswer):
            print('Well done, that is correct')
            score = score + 1
        else:
            print('Wrong, the correct answer was',rightanswer,'!')



print ("Well done " + name + "! You scored " , score,"out of 10")

if Class=="1" :
    my_file=open('Class1.txt','a')
    my_file.write(name)
    my_file.write(' , ')
    my_file.write(str(score))
    my_file.write('\n')
    my_file.close()

elif Class=="2" :
    my_file=open('Class2.txt','a')
    my_file.write(name)
    my_file.write(' , ')
    my_file.write(str(score))
    my_file.write('\n')
    my_file.close()

else :
    my_file=open('Class3.txt','a')
    my_file.write(name)
    my_file.write(' , ')
    my_file.write(str(score))
    my_file.write('\n')
    my_file.close()
```

Comment: Since this almost certainly about your [GCSE programming problem](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2gawvg/gcse_computing_programming_tasks_14_16_year_olds/), please do read [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166).

Comment: ok thank you, the problem is that there is very little information about the subject online, if you could lead me the right direction I would be very grateful.

Comment: @chessplayer101 I find that hard to believe, given the number of times this question has been asked in various forms over the last few months on SO alone.

Comment: @jonrsharpe excellent, any chance you could link me to one pls as I can't seem to find any :)

Comment: Nope! We aren't here to help you cheat on your GCSE coursework. If you insist on doing so, at least do it yourself.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok, it's just that no-one in my class or my teacher know how to solve this and we have 3 days to hand it in, looks like i'm getting a fail :'(

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of a standard error people get caught up on. The last section of your code needs to be replaced, well instead of the code going downwards put the lines of codes sidewards e.g heres and example from my project

```
enter code here
if usersClass == "1":
    with open("class1.txt","a+") as f:
        f.write("{}:Scored {} in {} seconds".format(username,correctAnswers,timeTaken))
```

So what you want to do is to re-direct/transform it to fit side by side, include your commas when doing so.